# WordPress Multisite - Cant acces subdirectory dashboard on local host using wamp

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, wampserver, multisite

Newbie here

Setting up a wordpress multisite in local environment but the problem is that I cannot access the dashboard for any of the created sub directories. This is the error I get

```
Forbidden 
You don't have permission to access /cs/
C:/wamp64/www/CS/wp-admin/ on this server.
```

`Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at localhost Port 80`

I can access the network admin as well as the main site admin panel.

Have configured everything as per requirements. Here is the `.htaccess` file content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cs/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) C:/wamp64/www/CS/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ C:/wamp64/www/CS/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Even deleting it did not help. Any suggestions what might be worng

Comment: For a WordPress site ALWAYS setup a Virtual Host and then re-install WP into that Virtual Host.

Comment: Thanks ill do that